# How can I insert DOCX type content created from a Ckeditor by HtmlToDocx, in to a table's cell created by Python DOCX?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, python-docx, html-to-docx

Function that converts CKeditor HTML content into DOCX using **HtmlToDocx**

```
def html_to_docs(html):
        new_parser.table_style = 'Table Grid'
        return new_parser.add_html_to_document(html, document)
```

Table created by **Python DOCX** table

```
# reportdetails is a django model

table = document.add_table(rows=reportdetails.count()-1, cols=5, style='Table Grid')
    table.allow_autofit = True 
    table.columns[0].width = Cm(2)
    table.columns[1].width = Cm(16)
    table.columns[2].width = Cm(2)
    table.columns[3].width = Cm(2)
    table.columns[4].width = Cm(2)
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
    hdr_cells[0].text = 'Research Area'
    hdr_cells[1].text = 'Findings'
    hdr_cells[2].text = 'Impact'
    hdr_cells[3].text = 'Recommendations'
    hdr_cells[4].text = 'Response'
    for reportdetail in reportdetails:
                
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
               
        row_cells[0].text = reportdetail.scope.scope_name
        finding = row_cells[1].add_paragraph()
        finding.add_run(str(html_to_docs(reportdetail.findings)))#inserting CKeditor content
        row_cells[2].text = reportdetail.impact
        row_cells[3].text = reportdetail.recommendations
        row_cells[4].text = reportdetail.response
```

Output I am getting on word document genetated:

[image: Output I am getting on word document genetated]

*No trees planted* should be the first finding and in the findings cell of row *Climate*, the table with those alphabets and the line after it should be in the second findings.

I have no idea why the findings cells contains **None**